# Update fields in a pivot table Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, crud

I have 3 tables  (2 + pivot) :

```
categories
    id
    admin_id
    created_at
    updated_at
    deleted_at

langs
    id
    langname_fr
    langname
    ....

lang_sector
    lang_id
    sector_id
    sectname
    sectshortname
    ....
```

I created a form which allow to create several entries depending the number of languages i defined ...

```
{!! Form::open( array('route' => 'maps.store','method' => 'POST') ) !!}
<fieldset>
    <legend>Nom du secteur</legend>

    @foreach($langs as $lang)

        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
            {{ Form::label( 'Nom du secteur en ' . $lang->langname_fr) }}
            {{ Form::text('sectname_lang_' . $lang->id, '' , [ 'class' => 'form-control m-input' ]) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
            {{ Form::label( 'Nom abrégé du secteur en ' . $lang->langname_fr ) }}
            {{ Form::text('sectshortname_lang_' . $lang->id, '', [ 'class' => 'form-control m-input' ]) }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</fieldset>
...

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If i want to create an entry in my database, i have to create several entries ...

```
public function sectorCreate(Request $request) {

    Sector::create(array(
        'admin_id' => Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
     ));

    $sector = Sector::all()->last();
    $sector_id = Sector::all()->last()->id;
    $countLang = Lang::count();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $countLang; $i++) {
        $insertSector[$i] = $sector->langs()->attach(
            $sector_id,
            [
                'lang_id' => $i,
                'sectname' => $request->input('sectname_lang_' .$i),
                'sectname_slug' => Str::slug($request->input('sectname_lang_' .$i)),
                'sectshortname' => $request->input('sectshortname_lang_' .$i),
                'sectdescription' => $request->input('sectdescription_lang_' .$i),
                'sectshortdescription' => $request->input('sectshortdescription_lang_' .$i),
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'deleted_at' => NULL
            ]
        );
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin.home')->with('success', 'Secteur créé');
}
```

Now my issue is to know how i can update the values of the database and to delete the entry ... I tried to read the documentation but i'm not sure i understood it.

For example

```
lang_id     sector_id      sectname      sectshortname 
-------------------------------------------------------
1          1           longname1      shortname1
2          1           longname2      shortname2
```

After update i would like to update sectname and sectshortname ... I have made several trials using sync, syncWithoutDetaching and updateExistingPivot without success...

I also add constraints by considering lang_id and sector_id as a primary key ...

**UPDATE ----------------------------------------------------------**

I modified the update method using sync and syncWithoutDetaching

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $sector = Sector::findOrFail($id);
    $countLang = Lang::count();

    $langs = Lang::all();
    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        $lang_id = $lang->id;
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $countLang; $i++) {
        $insertSector[$i] = $sector->langs()->sync(
            $sector->id,
            $lang_id,
            [
                'sectname' => $request->input('sectname_lang_' .$i),
                'sectname_slug' => Str::slug($request->input('sectname_lang_' .$i)),
                'sectshortname' => $request->input('sectshortname_lang_' .$i),
                'sectdescription' => $request->input('sectdescription_lang_' .$i),
                'sectshortdescription' => $request->input('sectshortdescription_lang_' .$i),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'deleted_at' => NULL
            ]
        );
    }
    return $insertSector;
    //return redirect()->route('maps.index')->with('success', 'updated');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) states the following:

When attaching a relationship to a model, you may also pass an array of additional data to be inserted into the intermediate table:

```
$user->roles()->attach($roleId, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

You got this part correct. Now for updating (and or deleting):

**Deleting**

```
$user->roles()->detach([1, 2, 3]);
```

This removes associated records and clears the intermediate table.

**Syncing Associations**

You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table:

```
$user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs:

```
$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

If you do not want to detach existing IDs, you may use the syncWithoutDetaching method:

```
$user->roles()->syncWithoutDetaching([1, 2, 3]);
```

**Conclusion**

Use sync, and set the attributes again. If you just want to update a few records, use the `syncWithoutDetaching`.

**Update**

Change your update code to this:

```
$insertSector[$i] = $sector->langs()->sync(
    $lang_id => 
    [
        'sectname' => $request->input('sectname_lang_' .$i),
        'sectname_slug' => Str::slug($request->input('sectname_lang_' .$i)),
        'sectshortname' => $request->input('sectshortname_lang_' .$i),
        'sectdescription' => $request->input('sectdescription_lang_' .$i),
        'sectshortdescription' => $request->input('sectshortdescription_lang_' .$i),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'deleted_at' => NULL
    ]
);
```

You passed both the `sector->id` and the `$lang_id` where you only needed to pass the `$lang_id` with attributes for the intermediate table.

Comment: @davidvera Updated my post

Comment: The code you provided is missing array brackets within the sync method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally thanks to Douwe de Haan i finally solved my issue for creating an entry with pivot table ... i guess i understood a little bit how it work now

Here is the method :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Sector::create(array(
        'admin_id' => Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ));

    $sector = Sector::all()->last();
    $countLang = Lang::count();
    $langs = Lang::all();

    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        $lang_id[] = $lang->id;
    }
    for ($i=0 ; $i < $countLang; $i++) {
        $insertSector[$i] = $sector->langs()->syncWithoutDetaching(
            [$lang_id[$i] =>
                [
                    'sectname' => $request->input('sectname_lang_' .$lang_id[$i]),
                    'sectname_slug' => Str::slug($request->input('sectname_lang_' .$lang_id[$i])),
                    'sectshortname' => $request->input('sectshortname_lang_' .$lang_id[$i]),
                    'sectdescription' => $request->input('sectdescription_lang_' .$lang_id[$i]),
                    'sectshortdescription' => $request->input('sectshortdescription_lang_' .$lang_id[$i]),
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    'deleted_at' => NULL
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
    return redirect()->route('maps.index')->with('success', 'Secteur créé');
}
```

For updating :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $sector = Sector::findOrFail($id);
    $countLang = Lang::count();

    $langs = Lang::all();
    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        $lang_id[] = $lang->id;
    }

    for ($i=0 ; $i < $countLang; $i++) {
        $insertSector[$i] = $sector->langs()->updateExistingPivot(
            $lang_id[$i],
                [
                    'sector_id' => $request->input('sector_id'),
                    'sectname' => $request->input('sectname_lang_' .$lang_id[$i]),
                    'sectname_slug' => Str::slug($request->input('sectname_lang_' .$lang_id[$i])),
                    'sectshortname' => $request->input('sectshortname_lang_' .$lang_id[$i]),
                    'sectdescription' => $request->input('sectdescription_lang_' .$lang_id[$i]),
                    'sectshortdescription' => $request->input('sectshortdescription_lang_' .$lang_id[$i]),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    'deleted_at' => NULL
                ]

        );
    }
    return $insertSector;
    //return redirect()->route('sectors.index')->with('success', 'Secteur mis à jour');
}
```